# Problem regarding pymol

Tags: python

I have a problem running Pymol software on Ubuntu 16.04. When I type pymol in the terminal it results in the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 272, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 247, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 237, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 582, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 528, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 412, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_nd import *
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd
```

Comment: What is the output of these commands : `dpkg -l | grep libpython2.7-minimal` and `python --version`

Comment: Also check if `env -i pymol` works or not ?